# What is the best ways to generate organic traffic?

Tags: seo

After introducing the Google Panda, bloggers and webmaster have been facing the great challenges. Duplicate content is the key issue and spam boat traffic is second issues for Google Panda
 in this great critical situation, how to beat Google Panda and what are the best sources to drive organic traffic?
Is there any pragmatic solution over this probolem?